# Update values based on previous record value manipulation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have the following table:

```
ID        Revision
1          A.1
1          A.2
1          A.4
1          A
1          B.1
1          B
1          C
1          D.1
```

I'd like to write a query to return the following:

```
ID        Revision     Version
1          A.1          A.1
1          A.2          A.2
1          A.4          A.4
1          A            A.5
1          B.1          B.1
1          B            B.2
1          C            C.1
1          D.1          D.1
```

Looking for help. My issue is that I need the version to be based on previous revision plus one.

Please advise.

Comment: Is it intentional that Version skips from A.2 to A.4?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID
    ,Revision
    ,Version = LEFT(Revision, 1)+'.'
        +CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, LEFT(Revision,1) ORDER BY ID, LEFT(Revision, 1), LEN(Revision) DESC, Revision) AS VARCHAR)
FROM @tbl 
ORDER BY ID, LEFT(Revision, 1), LEN(Revision) DESC, Revision
```

That will produce the result set you provided except that the Version number won't skip A.3

The reason the ORDER BYs are so awkward is to make sure a revision with no number always appears last.

Comment: Thanks OGhaza,I thought about what you suggested before but I have an issue with skipping a.4. I guess I will have to live with your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found an ugly solution. I joined the tables to create current revision and lag_revision. I then calculated a new field (version). My table name was documents.

```
example:
ID            REV        LAG_REV    Version
Xxx           A.1         (null)    A.1
Xxx           A.3         A.1       A.3
Xxx           A           A.3       A.4


  With numbered_docs as (
Select row_number() over (partition by ID order by creation_date) as rn, d.* from documents d
)
select z.ID,z.REVISION,z.lag_row_rev,z.Version into versions from (
Select d1.ID d1.revision, d2.revision as lag_row_rev,d1.CREATION_DATE
,(select case 
    when (CHARINDEX('.',d2.REVISION) > 0 and substring(d2.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d2.REVISION+'.')-1)=substring(d1.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION+'.')-1))
    then (substring(d2.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d2.REVISION)) + cast((cast(SUBSTRING(d2.REVISION,CHARINDEX('.', d2.REVISION)+1,LEN(d2.revision)) as integer)+1) AS varchar))
    when CHARINDEX('.',d1.REVISION) > 0 and CHARINDEX('.',d2.REVISION)=0 then substring(d1.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION)) + cast((cast(SUBSTRING(d1.REVISION,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION)+1,LEN(d1.revision)) as integer)) AS varchar)
    when d2.REVISION IS null and CHARINDEX('.',d1.REVISION) > 0 then substring(d1.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION)) + cast((cast(SUBSTRING(d1.REVISION,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION)+1,LEN(d1.revision)) as integer)) AS varchar) 
    when d2.REVISION IS null and CHARINDEX('.',d1.REVISION) = 0 then d1.REVISION+'.1'
    when CHARINDEX('.',d1.REVISION) = 0 and CHARINDEX('.',d2.REVISION) = 0 then d1.REVISION+'.1'
    when CHARINDEX('.',d2.REVISION) > 0 and CHARINDEX('.',d1.REVISION) > 0 and substring(d2.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d2.REVISION+'.')-1)<> substring(d1.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION+'.')-1)
    then substring(d1.REVISION,1,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION)) + cast((cast(SUBSTRING(d1.REVISION,CHARINDEX('.', d1.REVISION)+1,LEN(d1.revision)) as integer)) AS varchar)
    else NULL 
    end ) as [Version]
From numbered_docs d1
Left Join numbered_docs d2 on (d1.ID=d2_ID and d1.rn=d2.rn+1)
) z
order by z.ID,z.revision;
```